# Default place to save an unique file in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, file

I have a Cocoa application which reads and saves data in a sole file. This file is, in fact, a piece of the app; you can think about it as a configuration file. What would be the best place to save this file? Inside the `<App name>.app/` dir? In some hidden directory at the user's home?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put it in the `.app` package. It might not be writable for the user, and the settings file will then be global, not per-user.

The most appropriate place is probably in the user's application support directory: `~/Library/Application Support/FooApp` (where `FooApp` is the name of your application). You can build a path to this directory with the following bit of code (which may need to be adapted slightly to your purposes):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FooApp"];    // The file will go in this directory
NSString *saveFilePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"save_file.dat"];
```

Answer (score 3):

You would write your file into the application's application support folder. You can get the string to this folder like this:

```
- (NSString *)applicationSupportDirectory
{
    NSString *executableName =
        [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *result =
        [self
            findOrCreateDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
            inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
            appendPathComponent:executableName
            error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Unable to find or create application support directory:\n%@", error);
    }
    return result;
}
```

In addition to the implementation shown above it also creates the directory if is not already there.

Find a more detailed discussion in this article of [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/finding-or-creating-application-support.html)